# QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3

Tags: ros, qt, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I want to run `hector_geotiff`  to print map in a existed map ,
`rosrun hector_geotiff geotiff_saver` , Some thing happens.

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
QPainter::setFont: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[ INFO] [1432901455.048771190]: Out drawPath
[ INFO] [1432901455.052592317]: Writing image with file /map_20:10:53.tif failed with error Device not writable
[ INFO] [1432901455.052827484]: GeoTiff created in 1.661217 seconds
```

I search some infomation in Internet but I haven't find a useful one.

Could you help me ?

`Thanks!`

`Thanks!`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210160/qpainter::begin:-paint-device-returned-engine-==-0,-type:-3/) by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2015-05-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nico_robotech](https://answers.ros.org/users/24965/nico_robotech/) on 2015-10-31**:
Hi i'm having the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What path are you using to save the file to? I had the same problem when I tried to reference a path with the ~ to the home directory. Possibly the program used to create the map is not able to write to this directory - someone with a better knowledge of hector_geotiff can elaborate on this. I solved this by giving the full path to the directory.

Doesn't work: `<arg name = "map_file_path" value="~/maps"`

Works: `<arg name="/home/username/maps"`

---

Originally posted by [ematheson](https://answers.ros.org/users/26969/ematheson/) with karma: 16 on 2016-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2016-05-24**:
Thanks for your advice! I had solved this problem last years but I forget the detail approach.
I remember that I also give the full path to the directory. I think you are right. Thanks again.